# Error 500 sending python request as chrome

Tags: python, web-services, rest, google-chrome

I am dealing with this little error but I can not get the solution. I authenticate into a page and I had opened the "inspect/network" chrome tool to see what web service is called and how. I found out this is used:

[image]

I have censored sensitive data releated to the site. So, I have to do this same request using python, but I am always getting error 500 and the log on the server side is not showing helpful information (only java traceback).

This is the code of the request

```
response = requests.post(url,data = 'username=XXXXX&password=XXXXXXX')
```

URL has the same string that you see in the image under "General/Request URL" label.
Data has the same string that you see in the image under "Form Data".

It looks very simple request but I can not get it to work :( .

Best regards

Comment: The [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) has some examples of how to make a request that will help you.

Comment: Hello @trixn, I have already read that documentation was I did not find anything useful :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `request` **appears like coming from Chrome, other than sending correct `data` you need to specify headers as well**. The reason you got 500 error is probably there're certain settings on your server side disallowing traffic from "non-browsers".

So in your case, you need to add `headers`:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 
           'Accept-Encoding': gzip, deflate, 
           ...... # more
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 XXXXX...' # this line tells the server what browser/agent is used for this request
          }

response = requests.post(url,data = 'username=XXXXX&password=XXXXXXX', headers=headers)
```

**P.S.** If you are curious, default headers from `requests` are:

```
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> session.headers
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.13.0'}
```

As you can see the default `User-Agent` is `python-requests/2.13.0`, and some websites do block such traffic.